# Identify source of app install

Tags: android

Is there a way to determine the app store where the app was installed from? In my case, my app is published on Google Play as well as Samsung Apps and I am unable to find a mechanism to determine the source of the installation.

Comment: You can push a different build to each store with a static variable somewhere that denotes which store it is built for.  You can make this part of your build process with a build configuration file.  And, you can also make specific versions in the manifest for the different stores.

Comment: Thanks @Rich. I have seen suggestions like adding .g @ the end of the version code/name but I was looking for an approach that doesn't require me to modify the version code/name.

Comment: I did something once where the server wanted to know where the traffic was coming from.  I set a static variable in class and used an enum for this.  So, I'd modify this value in code manually before building.  I'm sure if I was using ANT or Gradle that there would be a more elegant way than changing the code and rebuilding, but that's what I did and as long as I tested it I felt comfortable with it.  I'd then package a different build for the various stores and make sure that the store name was in the file name of the apk